# How to solve one equation of $n$ variables, given that the variables take unique values from $\{1,2,3,4,...,n\}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, solve the equation:

$$a+3b+3c+d=22$$

where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ can only be $1$, $2$, $3$ and $4$. The same number cannot be taken by twice.

Thank  you!

Answer (score 1):

There are only $24$ possible arrangements
in general,
but particulars of an
individual problem
can speed things up.

In this case,
I notice the following:

$22-a-d$ has to be divisible by $3$.

It is symmetric in
$a$ and $d$
and also 
$b$ and $c$.
Therefore we can assume that
$a < d$ and $b < c$.

This should make things easier.